# Problems with accented characters when posting an image

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-social

I'm having a problem with Spring Social's Facebook integration while posting a photo with a caption: accented characters are being messed up. If I post anything else, the accents work okay, the problem seems to affect only photo captions.

The only reference to that problem I've found so far is this post:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?125252-Encoding-problem
And, as you can see, there seems to be no answer, yet.

Did anyone else stumble into this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, with both Spring Social Facebook and Spring Social Twitter.  I was using the following modules:

- spring-social-facebook 1.0.2-RELEASE
- spring-social-twitter 1.0.3-RELEASE
- spring-social-core 1.0.2-RELEASE

When I upgraded to the latest milestone builds (1.1.0.M4 for all), the problem was fixed in Facebook, but not in Twitter, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please provide link / latest version number ?

Comment: I found a work-around for the Twitter diacritics problem.  It is described in a comment for the Jira issue created to track it, SOCIALTW-37. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SOCIALTW-37?focusedCommentId=104466&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-104466